# How to run conditional statement after all comparison operator done

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm new on programming.

I want to make conditioonal statmenet using if,else inside of while loop.

```
  while(i < files.length){

         

            if(pathnameParams == files [i]){
                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/pages/'+pathnameParams.id));
                response.writeHead(200);
                response.end;
            }else{
                res.writeHead(404);
            };

        i++;

        }
```

but I want to response 404 after all conditional statment done such as all loop are false then run else{}.

thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag to store whether or not a match was found in the loop.

```js
let found = false;
while (i < files.length) { // note: this can be replaced with a for loop
    if (pathnameParams == files[i]) {
        // ...
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
if (!found) res.writeHead(404);
```

If this is inside a function, you can also return when a match is found and handle 404 after the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much I understand how it works! could you tell me what is '!' stand for?

Comment: @Null301 It is the [logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT).